# Guice Performance on Android

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, guice

As a Java developer I've become accustomed to having dependency injection available in applications.  For Android though, I am especially wary of performance.  What are the performance implications for using Guice in an Android app?  I assume there is some overhead, but is it significant enough that I should avoid using Guice?

My use of it would likely just be to inject a few shared objects into various activities.

Comment: You may be interested in Roboguice, and in particular in this ticket in the Roboguice tracker: http://code.google.com/p/roboguice/issues/detail?id=33 Basically, I don't know of any formal analysis of performance, but Roboguice (Guice with helpful Android stuff) is looking to add some JUnit tests for that.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I would likely be using roboguice if making use of Guice in this case.  I did not know about their Roboguice's junit tests though.  That would be nice to use to compare things.

Comment: I think Guice can be used on Android with reasonable performance. I know that Bob Lee, the creator of Guice, uses it in [Square](https://squareup.com/)'s Android app, for example.

Comment: @Colin: Square is the creator of a new DI framework named [tag:dagger].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of version 3, Guice caches reflective objects to improve performance. There's at least [one bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7811) out against dalvik to make annotation lookups faster, but the current performance is workable.

Answer (score 10):

I would avoid using DI in android as google suggests:
http://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html#DependencyInjection

Dagger solves some timing problems but still wastes memory for no real benefit.

Answer (score 6):

Roboguice (and Guice) can significantly degrade app startup time.  My moderately sized and not-yet-complete app took almost 15 seconds to start on an HTC EVO 4g.

Take a look at [Dagger](https://github.com/square/dagger) as an alternative that should provide virtually no startup overhead.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely use **Dagger 2** for Android projects if you're concerned with performance.

*Dagger 2 does not use reflection to scan your app’s code. Dagger’s static, compile-time implementation means that it can be used in Android apps without needless runtime cost or memory usage.*