# Lightweight Dependency Injection framework for Android

Tags: android, spring

I'm writing an Android application and as the code grows I realized that it needs to use a dependency injection framework for a better architecture.

(1) Is Spring too heavy for an Android apps?

(2) If yes, is there an alternative lightweight framework for this purpose?

Thanks!

Comment: Look at Andromeda http://andromeda.webuda.com. It is DI framework for Android in best tradition of Spring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a special extension of spring for Android: [Spring Android](http://www.springsource.org/spring-android).

> Spring Android is an extension of the Spring Framework that aims to simplify the development of native Android applications.

So I would say Spring is not to heavy for Android in general.

But of course you shold not use the `spring-all-in-one.jar`.

On the other hand [Google-Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/) would maybe a more natural choice. There is one Stack Overflow Question about Android and Guice: [Guice Performance on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067681/guice-performance-on-android)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'll give Guice a try, although after reading some posts it's mentioned that it doesn't have as complete features as Spring. But I suppose there must be a reason behind.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [RoboGuice](http://code.google.com/p/roboguice/)

[image: RoboGuice: Dependency Injection for Android]

Comment: It is now deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Success porting Spring framework(core, webmvc, hidernate, aop) + DWR + H2 on Android. 
Four months ago I decided to investigate the matter to migrate server applications built with Spring framework
on the Android platform. And at the moment I have a successful experience porting the two applications.

Answer (score 1):

You might also consider [Dagger](http://github.com/square/dagger) which is a JSR-330 compliant android-optimized dependency injection system.  It is inspired by Guice and written by Guice contributors.

It supports a code-generation approach, avoiding the substantial cost of reflection in android virtual machines, while deferring linking to avoid class-loading until the last responsible moment.  Side benefits of this are compile-time errors and graph analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at my project called **RoboSpring**. From the description:

RoboSpring is a (real) port of the Spring Framework to the Android platform. Additionally it offers preliminary support for functionality introduced by RoboGuice like injecting View references into Activities and more.
RoboSpring is based on version 3.1.0 RELEASE of Spring's **core**, **beans**, **context** and **aop** components. It offers the following functionality:

- Configure application components with a Spring configuration file
  (XML)
- Autowire your Android components with beans from the Spring application context.
- Inject the Android application context into your Spring Beans.
- Inject views into Activities.
- … and more

https://github.com/dthommes/RoboSpring

[image: RoboSpring - Inversion of Control for Android]

**HAPPY INJECTING!**

Answer (score 1):

You may find [Feather](https://github.com/zsoltherpai/feather) interesting, if low footprint and high performance is what you're after. The project includes some benchmarks comparing it vs PicoContainer, Guice, Dagger, Spring.

Comment: Feather is indeed faster than Dagger 1. It is ~2x faster according to Feather's author, but Dagger 2 is 5-10x faster than Feather on the same test. Feather doesn't require code generation unlike in Dagger 2.

Answer (score 1):

[Toothpick](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/toothpick) is also a good alternative.

[image: TP: Fast & Simple DI for Android]

***As fast as Dagger 2 and as simple as RoboGuice***

Note: Yes, I am one of the authors.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a new Spring project for Android: [Tiny Spring](http://code.google.com/p/tiny-spring/). It solves the very basics of XML configuration but doesn't do everything that Spring does.