# ButterKnife - bind drawable resource

Tags: android, android-drawable, butterknife

How to eliminate the following initialization code using ButterKnife annotations?

```
private Drawable mExpandDrawable;
private Drawable mCollapseDrawable;

void init() {
    mExpandDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_expand_small_holo_light);
    mCollapseDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_collapse_small_holo_light);
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [@BindDrawable](https://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/javadoc/butterknife/BindDrawable.html) from ButterKnife 7 API.

```
import butterknife.BindDrawable;

@BindDrawable(R.drawable.ic_expand_small_holo_light)
protected Drawable mExpandDrawable;
@BindDrawable(R.drawable.ic_collapse_small_holo_light)
protected Drawable mCollapseDrawable;

void init() {
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
}
```

There are 
@BindString,
@BindInt,
@BindDimen,
@BindColor,
@BindBool
for other resource types.

Comment: Note that the fields you are binding to cannot be private. They must have at least package visibility so the generated code can modify them.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27244742/butterknife-view-injection

Answer (score 0):

Use @Bind property in ButterKnife as mentioned below.

```
@BindDrawable(R.drawable.ic_expand_small_holo_light) Drawable mExpandDrawable;
```

and in onCreate after setContentView method is called, use bind method of ButterKnife (If you are using Activity).

```
@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.simple_activity);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    // TODO Use fields...
}
```

If you are using Fragment, use the below code to initialize ButterKnife:

```
@Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fancy_fragment, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    // TODO Use fields...
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Please, do not overuse <blockquote> tag in markdown.

Comment: @naXa: Sorry, I didn't get you pal! could you please make necessary edits, if needed.

Comment: I mean, the orange highlighting is for citation only.